# Pulling lists of lists from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, nested-lists

I have a text file filled with music lyrics.  An example of this:

```
NAME: The Cave SINGER: Mumford and Sons

It's empty in the valley of your heart
The sun, it rises slowly as you walk
Away from all the fears
And all the faults you've left behind

The harvest left no food for you to eat
You cannibal, you meat-eater, you see
But I have seen the same
I know the shame in your defeat

But I will hold on hope
And I won't let you choke
On the noose around your neck
```

How do I pull it so it is stored as a list of lists?

```
Output: [[It's empty in the valley of your heart], [The sun, it rises slowly 
 as you walk] [Away from all the fears], [And all the faults you've left 
 behind] etc.]
```

There are multiple songs and they each need to be their own list.

```
 with open("songs.txt", "r") as new:
       doc = new.readline()
       lyrics = []
       for line in doc:
            if "NAME:" not in line:
                 lyrics.append([line])
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pretty close, here is what you can use:

```
def read_file(filename):
    lyrics = []

    with open(filename) as file:
        next(file)
        for line in file.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                lyrics.append([line])

    return lyrics

print(read_file("songs.txt"))
# [["It's empty in the valley of your heart"], ['The sun, it rises slowly as you walk'], ['Away from all the fears'], ["And all the faults you've left behind"], ['The harvest left no food for you to eat'], ['You cannibal, you meat-eater, you see'], ['But I have seen the same'], ['I know the shame in your defeat'], ['But I will hold on hope'], ["And I won't let you choke"], ['On the noose around your neck']]
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple songs, such as the file below:

```
NAME: The Cave SINGER: Mumford and Sons

It's empty in the valley of your heart
The sun, it rises slowly as you walk
Away from all the fears
And all the faults you've left behind

The harvest left no food for you to eat
You cannibal, you meat-eater, you see
But I have seen the same
I know the shame in your defeat

But I will hold on hope
And I won't let you choke
On the noose around your neck

NAME: I Will Wait SINGER: Mumford and Sons

Well I came home
Like a stone
And I fell heavy into your arms
These days of dust
Which we've known
Will blow away with this new sun

But I'll kneel down
Wait for now
And I'll kneel down
Know my ground

And I will wait, I will wait for you
And I will wait, I will wait for you
```

You could store these songs in a dictionary:

```
import re

def read_file(filename):

    # dictionary of all the songs
    all_songs = {}

    with open(filename) as file:

        # convert file into one big string
        file_str = file.read()

        # get the substring locations of "Name"
        song_locs = [s.start() for s in re.finditer("NAME", file_str)]


        # get the songs into a list based on locations
        songs = []
        for start, end in zip(song_locs[:-1], song_locs[1:]):
            songs.append(file_str[start:end])

        # get last song
        songs.append(file_str[end:])


        # add each song to dictionary
        for song in songs:

            # get each line splitted by newline
            lines = [line for line in song.split("\n") if line]

            # adding song title/singer as key to dictionary, and lyrics as the values
            song_title, lyrics = lines[0], [[line] for line in lines[1:]]
            all_songs[song_title] = lyrics

        return all_songs

print(read_file("songs.txt"))
```

Which outputs:

```
{'NAME: The Cave SINGER: Mumford and Sons': [["It's empty in the valley of your heart"], ['The sun, it rises slowly as you walk'], ['Away from all the fears'], ["And all the faults you've left behind"], ['The harvest left no food for you to eat'], ['You cannibal, you meat-eater, you see'], ['But I have seen the same'], ['I know the shame in your defeat'], ['But I will hold on hope'], ["And I won't let you choke"], ['On the noose around your neck']], 'NAME: I Will Wait SINGER: Mumford and Sons': [['Well I came home'], ['Like a stone'], ['And I fell heavy into your arms'], ['These days of dust'], ["Which we've known"], ['Will blow away with this new sun'], ["But I'll kneel down"], ['Wait for now'], ["And I'll kneel down"], ['Know my ground'], ['And I will wait, I will wait for you'], ['And I will wait, I will wait for you']]}
```

And you can access each songs lyrics like this:

```
>>> d = read_file("songs.txt")
>>> print(d['NAME: The Cave SINGER: Mumford and Sons'])
[["It's empty in the valley of your heart"], ['The sun, it rises slowly as you walk'], ['Away from all the fears'], ["And all the faults you've left behind"], ['The harvest left no food for you to eat'], ['You cannibal, you meat-eater, you see'], ['But I have seen the same'], ['I know the shame in your defeat'], ['But I will hold on hope'], ["And I won't let you choke"], ['On the noose around your neck']]

>>>> print(d['NAME: I Will Wait SINGER: Mumford and Sons'])
[['Well I came home'], ['Like a stone'], ['And I fell heavy into your arms'], ['These days of dust'], ["Which we've known"], ['Will blow away with this new sun'], ["But I'll kneel down"], ['Wait for now'], ["And I'll kneel down"], ['Know my ground'], ['And I will wait, I will wait for you'], ['And I will wait, I will wait for you']]
```

**Note:** The dictionary assumes that you will supply the NAME and the SINGER of the of the songs.

Comment: This is great, but how do I differentiate among different songs?  The function above will append all lines of all songs to one massive list.

Comment: @Zoey Oh I misunderstood your question, Can you give an example of a file containing more that one song?

Comment: NAME: Teenage Dream  SINGER: Katy Perry

You think I'm pretty
Without any make-up on
You think I'm funny
When I tell the punchline wrong
I know you get me
So I let my walls come down, down

Before you met me
I was alright
But things were kinda heavy
You brought me to life

NAME: Firework SINGER: Katy Perry

Do you ever feel like a plastic bag
Drifting through the wind, wanting to start again?
Do you ever feel, feel so paper-thin
Like a house of cards, one blow from caving in?

Comment: Does the above answer help at all?

Comment: Glad you liked it. Their are some modifications you can make to the above code, to make it better. But it should do what you want for the most part.